# Tank_Auth on IE7 -- login redirects to 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, internet-explorer-7, tankauth

I am using CI 2.0 and Tank_Auth.

On IE7 (Win XP), there is the weirdest behavior. I fill out the login page info, and when I click on "Login", it takes me to a 404 error on this page:

```
http://example.com/auth/index.html
```

My CI error logs show this

```
ERROR - 2011-04-11 13:00:49 --> 404 Page Not Found --> auth/index.html
```

Needless to say, this does not happen on any other browser, including FF, Cr, Saf ***and IE8***.

I have also read about several issues re cookies with IE7, have made changes to the cookie names (removing underscores) and duration to no avail. I even wonder if this has anything to do with cookies at all.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I should troubleshoot this? I've been trying this issue at the CI forums, but no solution.

Any roadmap or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does sound weird. What controller/method is the login form posting to? Have you tried making a simple form NOT using TankAuth to see if the problem is recreated? I would first troubleshooting  without TankAuth and see how you get on, gradually building up functionality to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks george, actually that's what i did beginning with the raw login page of tank_auth and building from there - at the end i'm embarrassed to admit there was a simple 3-word JS attached to my login button that I failed to delete (it was redirecting to the 404 page) - you get the points because that's what should be done in such a bizarre situation - cheers